# State's build() method keep get called when I am using image_picker and image_crop library in iOS device only

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using these two libraries for picking and cropping images from gallery or camera ([image_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) and [image_cropper](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_cropper)) when I select image from gallery and want to perform further operation then `build` method is called automatically and changes the flow of my code.

In android devices this code is working fine and `build` method is called only once, but in iOS device `build` is called when I select image from gallery and after I crop this image.

In iOS devices as the device's photo library opened then `build` method is called and when crop is called then again `build` method is called of Drawer class.

This issue is occurring in Drawer only, if I call my TextRobo class as `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/textRobo');` then this works fine.

**Drawer Class**

```
_getDrawerItemWidget(int pos, String title) {


  switch (pos) {
    case 0:
      if(title.contains("From Gallery"))

        return new TextRobo();
      if(title.contains("From Camera"))
        return new TextRoboCamera();
      else if(widget.fragment_class.contains("Translate"))
        return new TranslateLangue(widget.textToTranslate);
      else
        return new TranslateLangue("");


      break;

    case 1:

      if(title.contains("From Gallery"))
        return new BarCodeRobo();
      else
        return new BarCodeQuick();

      break;
    case 2:
      return new TranslateLangue("");

  //default:
  //return new TranslateLangue("");
  }


}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

print('Building widget');


return new Scaffold(

appBar: new AppBar(
  iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
  title: new Text("RoboScan",
    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
),

  drawer: new Drawer(
    child: new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container( height: 140.0, color: Colors.orange,
        child: new Center(child:
          new Text('RoboScan', style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
          fontSize:25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        ),
        new Column(
            children: drawerOptions)
      ],
    ),

  ),
  body: _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedDrawerIndex, widget.fragment_class  ),
);
}
```

**Image Picker and Crop class(TextRobo)**

```
 File _imageFile;
 List<VisionText> _currentTextLabels = <VisionText>[];
 FirebaseVisionTextDetector textDetector = 
 FirebaseVisionTextDetector.instance;


 @override
 void initState() {
 // TODO: implement initState
//scanImage();
 super.initState();

 _getAndScanImage();

 }


Future<void> _getAndScanImage() async {
setState(() {
  _imageFile = null;
 // _imageSize = null;
});

 final File imageFile =
 await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);


 _cropImage(imageFile);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The widget's `build` method **is meant to called frequently**. I would recommend you re-structure things in order to allow your build method to be called as required by the Flutter framework.

Note: It's a good idea to push 'state' as far down the tree as possible (towards the leaf widgets) in order to minimize this effect of widget rebuilding due to state change.

In your case, you may want to consider removing `_getAndScanImage()` from the `initState` method. Having your render flow impact your interactions is not a good pattern.

**Can you try having the `_getAndScanImage()` method be triggered by a button press** or some other user trigger action rather than the rendering lifecycle in `initState`?